# How to control multiple framework versions of the same project in git

Tags: .net, git, version-control

Let's say I have a `Project` called `Tools`.

Tools is a `ClassLibrary` containing ExtensionMethods, Helpers, etc.

Different products use different references Tools compiled in various .net framework versions.

I've worked with TFS for a long time so I have problems migrating to git.

[image]

This is the structure I have on disk **AND** also in the "Source Control Explorer" in Visual Studio.

I am used to use the Visual Studio GUI to Merge and Branch Changesets across Branches.

[image]

I was not able to create a similar environment with git.
Where I can push from one branch to the other back and forth.

I would like to have just 1 repository for "Tools" while having the different branches stored on disk (checked out or not).

Comment: I'm bit lost here, what is preventing you from having similar structure to TFS in git?

Comment: I dont quite understand what you are trying to do. Whatever file structure you have, you can push it to git. Please use better names than "Test", so that people understand what you are trying to do. At first glance, it seems as if you just want to have multiple projects within one solution but I doubt that thats your problem here.

Comment: @Smogen I hope it is more clear now :/ ?

Comment: @FelixD. I still dont quite understand. What is your goal here?
Are you trying to have the root/Tool/ contain source files that are used in multiple projects? Ore do you want to have the projects net###/Tools/ to reference an assembly built by root/Tool? Or do you want to have shared source files/assemblies in root/Tool and specify the product further in different version by the net###/Tool Projects? What exactly is your goal here? Because I dont quite get why you cant just have the file structure that you show above pushed to git and build your project structure according to your needs.

Comment: @Smogen Sorry it is so hard to understand. I don't know how to make it more clear. Basically I have 4 csproj files, so 4 folders containing sourcecode of the "same" project (build using different framework versions). Since it is 1 **Project** I feel like having more than 1 repository is wrong (maybe that assumption itself is wrong). I would like to have changes tracked not for every file in that single repro but track the changes "branch" by branch (like i had it before using TFS). Using more than 1 repro makes it hard to push changes from one branch to the other.

Answer (score 2):

I think I understand what you want to accomplish based on your comments and I'll propose a solution but please let me state first that the way TFS and GIT work with branches and merges are quite different. In GIT you don't have the need to download every branch to a separate folder like we used to do with TFS; in GIT you work and switch branches on the same working folder quite easily.

If you need have all the branches checked out to be able to build faster (or whatever) what I propose is:

1) Consider one folder/build as the master/trunk/latest (or any terminology you are familiar with) and use that as the main branch
2) Clone the same repo to different folders, each folder representing the build (branch) you want to use
3) In each folder/repo checkout the branch you are going to be working in
4) You can work with the different branches on these folders and push/pull to all the other ones while having only one repo

Please, I repeat again, this is not the ideal way of working with GIT. If you're using newer versions of Visual Studio the integration with GIT works seamlessly.

Answer (score 0):

If your application reference `Test`, then you could have multiple repositories (it is not so bad, so just consider it). Then, `Test` could be done as submodule (for example, check [this link](https://gist.github.com/gitaarik/8735255), or you could find plenty of others) in each of your repositories (`net452`, `net461`), etc.
Then, you could maintain `Test` at single place - separate repository - and push changes to projects repositories, which use `Test`.